# Fitting a Survival Function with OLS - What Points To Use?

Tags: survival, least-squares, hazard, kaplan-meier

I'm trying to fit a survival function that is generated from discrete data. Is it correct to use Ordinary Least Squares, and if so what points do I use to do the fit?

[image]

A, B or C? Or other?

Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Thank you.

Edit: Some more info as requested. I’m comparing methods to fit power law distributions of rank-frequency data. Similar to White et al’s “On estimating the exponent of power-law frequency distributions”, but specifically on rank-frequency distributions, which behave slightly differently to general power laws.

I was purposefully a bit vague initially because I know that fitting OLS to a ccdf is problematic, not to mention on a log-log scale. Nevertheless the method is used often in the literature. And so I want to implement it in the best way possible, and then compare with other methods such as maximum likelihood estimation.

So, if you absolutely had to fit a ccdf using OLS how would you go about it?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  What is the underlying purpose of your analysis?  This could be a reasonable approach, but I suspect, depending on, what you are trying to do, that there are better methods like models for discrete time models:  https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s6

Comment: OLS won't yield a valid survival function, which must output values between 0 and 1. Also, why fit an existing survival function instead of the underlying data? Could you edit to include more detail about your problem and goals?

Comment: Thank you @user20169. I’ve added some more context.

Comment: Thanks @StatsStudent I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comments, I typically wouldn't recommend using OLS for this type of data.
But given that you are insistent in your update on using OLS in and given that you want to use this method to seemingly compare your work with using OLS methods which, according to you is a standard approach in your field, then I'd recommend simply attempting A, B, and C, and then report all your results.  Alternatively, if you are sure you need to use OLS, and if your interest only lies in accurate prediction, I'd recommend you try all 3 methods on a training data set.  Then make your predictions on a hold-out sample and chose the method that performs best (i.e. whichever methods results in the smallest [Mean Squared Predicted Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_prediction_error)).